# int argc MY_ATTRIBUTE((unused)) means

Tags: mysql, c

I was going through the source code of libmysql.c .I came accross

```
int STDCALL mysql_server_init(int argc MY_ATTRIBUTE((unused)),
              char **argv MY_ATTRIBUTE((unused)),
              char **groups MY_ATTRIBUTE((unused)))
```

what does argc MY_ATTRIBUTE means .What does it means to use int argc MY_ATTRIBUTE()  if i am correct int is the return type MY_ATTRIBUTE is the function name.I want to know the purpose of argc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**GCC C Extensions:**](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.2/gcc/Variable-Attributes.html)

> **unused**
>
> This attribute, attached to a variable, means that the variable
>   is meant to be possibly unused. GCC will not produce a warning for
>   this variable.

This means that when the variable is not used the compiler gcc will not give a warning about that variable.

***Example:***

```
int main(void)
{
  int a; // warning as variable a not used
  int b __attribute__((unused)); 
}
```

When compiling this program with `gcc -Wall` or simply `gcc -Wunused-variable` you will get:

```
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:7:6: warning: unused variable ‘a’ [-Wunused-variable]
int a; 
    ^
```

---

Concerning now `int argc MY_ATTRIBUTE((unused))`:

`argc` is an **integer parameter** that compiler will not give a warning if it is not used inside the function `STDCALL mysql_server_init` definition.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a MACRO, [this](https://github.com/twitter/mysql/blob/master/libmysql/libmysql.c#L121) version is more clear:

```
int STDCALL mysql_server_init(int argc __attribute__((unused)),
                  char **argv __attribute__((unused)),
                  char **groups __attribute__((unused)))
```

This just mean, I don't use this argument.